# MySQL 5.7 compare row to previous row

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7

I have a table containing daily sales. Not every day has sales (so there are 'missing' rows in the table).

I'm using MySQL 5.7, so there are no window functions available.

The structure of the table is date(timestamp), sales volume

| date | sales volume | +/- prev DAY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-18 | 76 | 0 |
| 2022-10-17 | 131 | 55 |
| 2022-10-16 | 110 | -21 |
| 2022-10-15 | 102 | -8 |
| 2022-10-14 | 201 | 99 |
| 2022-10-10 | 100 | -101 |

As an example, sales on 14-10 were 201, which were 99 more than sales for the previous row (15/10, 102)

I wish to derive the value in the 3rd column, comparing sales for the particular day, with those of the previous row (which isn't always the previous day), but can't seem to get anything working.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share sample input table formatted as an actual table, and expected output?

Comment: On your version you can easily obtain needed output using user-defined variable.

Comment: *`+/- prev DAY`* - by fact you show the difference while compare with NEXT day.

Answer (score 3):

```sql
SELECT `sales volume` - @previous `+/- prev DAY`,
       `date`,
       @previous := `sales volume` `sales volume`
FROM test
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @previous := NULL) init_variable
ORDER BY `date` DESC
```

| +/- prev DAY | date | sales volume |
| --- | --- | --- |
| *null* | 2022-10-18 | 76 |
| 55 | 2022-10-17 | 131 |
| -21 | 2022-10-16 | 110 |
| -8 | 2022-10-15 | 102 |
| 99 | 2022-10-14 | 201 |
| -101 | 2022-10-10 | 100 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pV47MeWa)

The expressions ordering in the output list and ORDER BY expression are critical. If you want to reorder output columns and/or output rows then use this query as subquery and set needed columns order and/or rows ordering in outer query.

Comment: you are a legend!